# Can JcaPEMWriter generate PKCS#8 output?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pem, pkcs#1, pkcs#8

The following code uses the `JcaPEMWriter` class from BouncyCastle to output a randomly generated RSA private key in PKCS#1 format (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048, null);
    final KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    final PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    final StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
    try (JcaPEMWriter w = new JcaPEMWriter(s)) {
        w.writeObject(privateKey);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Is there any way to make `JcaPEMWriter` output PKCS#8 format (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply a slightly different object to the PEMWriter, namely a [`JcaPKCS8Generator`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPKCS8Generator.html). The following should work

```
try (JcaPEMWriter w = new JcaPEMWriter(s)) {
    w.writeObject(new JcaPKCS8Generator(privateKey, null));
}
```